# Nginx & Node inside the same Docker container

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, reverse-proxy

I know that this is against the accepted convention but I need to run Nginx alongside a node.js server inside the **same** Docker container.  I have no issues spinning up the container and getting Nginx and Node working alongside.  Nginx works on Port 443 which is exposed by the container. The Node server listens on Port 8080 and is reverse proxied by Nginx

```
location /node/index.js {
 proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
 proxy_set_header Host $host;
 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header X_Forwarded_For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Here is what I find

- Access to the resources, `https://example.com/text.txt` on the Nginx server is straightforward
- I startup the Nodejs server `nodejs index.js & disown` which has been configured to output a few diagnostic messages to a log file. Those messages tell me that the server is working just fine.
- I can Telnet to Port 8080 from inside the Docker container - once again indicating that the Node server i sup and running
- Precisely the same configuration but with Nginx running on a **"real"** server with Node running on the same server offers acceess to the Node server with no issues.
- However, when I attempt to access the Node server running inside the Nginx Docker container, say, `https://example.com/node/index.js` I get a 404 error.

Examining my Nginx logs reveals that the request did reach Nginx inside its Docker host. However, examining the Node server log file indicates that the request never got forwarded.

It is not clear to me why this could be happening. From what I can tell when Nginx is running inside a Docker container it is failing to act as a reverse proxy for Node running inside the same container.

For good measure I tried EXPOSing the Node port, 8080 and starting up the Docker container with `-p 8080:8080 -p 443:443` but that made no difference.  I'd be most grateful to anyone who might be able to shed any light on what is going on here.

Comment: Copy/paste error or is your [syntax](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) a bit off?

Comment: @tuomur - more a case of butter fingers as I typed this question. Edited now,

Comment: could you provide a Dockerfile that we could use to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I have app using nginx & node in one docker container and it works just fine. But my first question is why you set location block like "location /node/index.js" ? Second which nginx docker image you use ?

Comment: It has been a few years since I posted that question.  I honestly cannot remember what Nginx docker image I might have used.  I have a vague recollection that I started with an empty Docker container and then built my own image but I could be wrong.